# What is mean by This Exception in Apache Spark?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.DelimitRegExIterator.getFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Ledu/stanford/nlp/util/Function;)Ledu/stanford/nlp/objectbank/IteratorFromReaderFactory;
here is my pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Fyp</groupId>
  <artifactId>DSS</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                  </configuration>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.Polarity</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.2</version>
           </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency> 
    <dependency>  
      <groupId>jaws</groupId>  
      <artifactId>jaws</artifactId>  
      <version>1.2</version>  
      <type>jar</type>  
      <scope>system</scope>  
      <systemPath>D:/Users/Developer/workspace/DSS/lib/jaws-bin.jar</systemPath>  
 </dependency>  
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

         <dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.2</version>
   </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>edu.washington.cs.knowitall.stanford-corenlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-ner-models</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: Did you check that the dependencies are being packaged as well?

Comment: yes dependencies are packaged

Comment: Does it support java 8? Maybe try compile it with Java 7 and check?